# Consulta sobre pasar Sistema de monocliente a multicliente

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, base-de-datos, aplicación-web

qué tal les va? En esta oportunidad quisiera hacerles una consulta sobre una aplicación propia que estoy expandiendo. Inicialmente comencé a desarrollar la idea de este sistema, como especie de practica en mi curso de php, y asi ir ampliando mis conocimientos. Ahora que ya tengo el sistema terminado, quisiera hacerle una ampliación más, pero me he quedado un poco trabado en la forma cómo debo hacerla, espero puedan ayudarme y orientarme con sus sabios consejos.

Verán, es un sistema de ventas, compras y almacén multisucursales (excelente para administrar un negocio que tiene varias sucursales)

El esquema del sistema es más o menos asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

se puede agregar sucursales, cada sucursal tendra sus empleados, estos tendrán su usuario y clave para acceder al sistema con ciertos privilegios que el usuario administrador les podrá dar. Hasta ahi todo bien, el detalle es que quiero configurar el sistema para que ahora sea multinegocios y poder subirlo a la red y vender membresias para acceder a este.

He diseñado un formulario de Registro para que por ejemplo los clientes(dueños de los negocios) se registren, cancelen una suscripción y puedan usar el sistema para administrar su negocio. Me he creado un panel de administración donde pretendo recibir la información de los registros de cada cliente y monitorear cuantos clientes tengo ya registrados y usando el sistema, suspender su suscripción, enviarles mensajes notificando que no han pagado, etc.

En definitiva, lograr algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para eso me he creado en la base de datos ya existente, tablas para registrar la información de los clientes, los pagos, las notificaciones, entre otras.

en esta imagen se muestran un ejemplo de tres tablas del sistema actual (usuario, sucursal y empleados) y un ejemplo de una nueva tabla que agregue (clientes)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A partir de allí me he estancado, porque no se cómo configurar bien la base de datos (o si debo hacerlo) y las sesiones para pasar de un sistema para un solo negocio, a un sistema que pueda ser usado por múltiples negocios. Estaba pensando incluso en crear una nueva base de datos tal vez y establecer conexión con la ya creada. El manejo de sesiones actual es bastante sencillo, adaptado a un sistema para un solo negocio. Pero supongo debo hacer un cambio grande en el manejo de las sesiones.

Mi duda es como llevar el sistema a este siguiente nivel. 
Si tuvieran alguna información, guías o tutoriales de ejemplo sobre sistemas de este tipo, que pudieran facilitarme, para guiarme se los agradecería muchísimo. Cualquier recomendación sera bien recibida.

PD: El sistema no esta realizado usando ningún framework. 
Lenguajes: PHP, HTML, JAVASCRIPT. BD: MySQL, Uso de tecnologias AJAX.

Comment: Tendrás q crear una tabla usuario y una tabla rol con una relación por ejemplo 1-M. Por ultimo relaciona esa tabla usuario con la tabla sucursal, con una relación 1-M igual. A tus consultas para obtener la información pues deberás agregarle siempre el filtro q garantice sea solo información de la sucursal a la q pertenece el usuario autenticado

Comment: en el sistema que ya esta hecho, yo tengo una tabla usuario. Mira la ultima imagen de la publicación. Ahi coloque un pequeño ejemplo de 3 tablas que son usuario, empleado y sucursal. Esas tablas ya las tiene el sistema. En la tabla empleado se registran los empleados del negocio y aparte ahi se le asigna usuario y clave, que son los que podra usar para entrar al sistema. Pueden haber empleados con rol: administrador, empleado de una sucursal o cliente.

Comment: en la tabla usuario lo que gestiono son los roles... Pero estos roles son para manejar el sistema en modo monocliente... No se como expandir esto.

Comment: Por que no llamas a cada tsbla por su nombre, la tabla rol almacena roles no identificsdores de usuario, te estas enredando con los terminos. Recuerda q cada.tabla almacena multiples registros. Así q tendrás varias sucursales relacionadas con sus empleados y cada empleado tendrá asignado su rol. Ya te digo, todo se basa en condicionar tus consultas a la sucursal del empleado autenticado. Ese es un dato q puedes almacenar en la sesion.

Comment: lo se, tendria que crear entonces una nueva tabla usuario? y aparte una tabla rol

Comment: Solo tendrss en tu sistema una tsbla usuario y una tabla rol. La tabla usuario es lo mismo q la tabla empleado a los efectos

Comment: yo tenia pensado crear la tabla clientes, y en esa tabla crear un enlace con las otras tablas como usuario, empleado y sucursal. La tabla clientes si a necesito para efectos de manejar los datos de mis clientes (o sea, los negocios) y poder gestionar los pagos de las suscripciones al sistema. Solo quería asignar a cada cliente sus privilegios para que usen el sistema y manejen su negocio allí... el manejo de sesiones podrian ser tipo como las de facebook. eso tenia pensado